# How can I get the string of 5 digit hexadecimal in Python?

Tags: python, encryption, utf-8, hex

I have an integer that I converted to hexadecimal as follows:

```
  int_N = 193402
  hex_value = hex(int_N)
```

it gives me the following hex: **0x2f37a**.

**I want to convert the hexadecimal to string**.

I tried this:

```
  bytes.fromhex(hex_value[2:]).decode('ASCII')
  # [2:] to get rid of the 0x
```

however, it gives me this error:

```
   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Then I tried with **decode('utf-8') instead of ASCII**, but it gave me this error:

```
   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Any suggestions how to fix that? whay it's not converting the hexadecimal '0x2f37a' to a string?

After reading some documentations, I assume maybe Hexadecimal should contain even number of digits in order to covert to string, but wasn't able to do so or make it even, as I'm using hex() and it gave me the value.

Thanks and really appreciate any help!

Comment: Does `hex_value[2:]` not work for you?

Comment: Because `type(hex_value)` tells me that it's already a `str`

Comment: There is no real question in there. Please clarify what you are asking for.

Comment: @intedgarhex_value[2:] works, it gives me 2f37a. but when I want to get the string it does not work.

Comment: @VoNWooDSoN how to convert the hexadeciman 0x2f37a to string?

Comment: "it gives me the following hex".  `'0x2f37a'` **is** a string.  That's what `hex()` returns.  `hex(193402)[2:]` Removes the `0x` from the string and returns the *string* `'2f37a'`.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the struct and binascii module.

```
import struct
import binascii

int_N = 193402

s      = struct.Struct(">l")
val    = s.pack(int_N)
output = binascii.hexlify(val)

print(output) #0002f37a
```

find out more about c_type packing [here at PMOTW3](https://pymotw.com/3/struct/).

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to convert it to a string, no other requirements, then this works (I'll pad it to 8 characters here):

```
int_N = 193402
s = hex(int_N)[2:].rjust(8, '0') # get rid of '0x' and pad to 8 characters
print(s, type(s))
```

Output:

```
0002f37a <class 'str'>
```

...proving that it's a string type.  If you're interested in getting the individual *bytes*, then something like this will demonstrate:

```
for b in bytes.fromhex(s):
    print(b, type(b))
```

Output:

```
0 <class 'int'>
2 <class 'int'>
243 <class 'int'>
122 <class 'int'>
```

... showing all four bytes (from eight hex digits) and proving they're integers.  The key here is *an even number of characters* I chose 8) so that `fromhex()` can decode it.  An odd number of bytes will give a `ValueError`.

Now you can either use the string or the bytes as you please.

Answer (score 0):

Format numbers the way you like with f-strings (format strings).  Here are examples of various forms of hexadecimal and binary:

```py
>>> n=193402
>>> f'{n:x} {n:08x} {n:#x} {n:020b}'
'2f37a 0002f37a 0x2f37a 00101111001101111010'
```

See [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).